# upgrading to mac osx el capitan

Tags: django, git, macos, osx-lion, osx-elcapitan

disclaimer: web development newbie.

I will be purchasing a macbook today. I currently own a macbook that i bought back in 2012, with 10.7.5 Lion as my OS version. I can't seem to upgrade to any newer versions under this laptop, and I am having the hardest time even trying to get Git onto my computer without it giving me the Illegal 4 error.  so after much thinking, I decided to just invest in a new laptop (I heard with version 10.9 and higher, you can install Git straight form the command line!)

I am a beginner programmer in python/django, and am planning to use a combination of Git/Github/SourceTree/Bitbucket throughout my deployment process.

If I buy any laptop from Apple today, it will come with El Capitan as default. Would this make it difficult for me to install any of the above softwares I mentioned? Woud El Capitan crash my apps or make it difficult for me to use the current mainstream methods of delployment?

Answer (score 3):

No you will be fine, I've been doing Ruby on Rails development on several machines running El Capitan. I would recommend installing `git` with `home-brew`.

[homebrew](http://brew.sh) is a great package manager for OS X